# How do I Automatically insert a new record into a child table when a new record is added to a parent table in Lightswitch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch Desktop Client application in C#. There is a parent table/entity called Participants and a child table called HouseIncomes. One of the field/properties in HouseIncomes is a string property called CurrentLevel with a choice list of Yes and No. When a new record is created in the Participants parent table, how can one record be added to the child HouseIncomes table with the default of "Yes" in the CurrentLevel field?

Comment: A Boolean data type with a checkbox control for the CurrentLevel property would be more appropriate than a string data type with a Yes/No choice list but either would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C#, this should work for your scenario:

Open up your Data Source, click in "Write Code" and select the Participants_Inserted option. (see image below) enter code similar to this: the naming conventions might be slightly out but I have guessed at what yours may be:

```
    partial void Participants_Inserted(Participants entity)
    {
        HouseIncome houseIncome = DataWorkspace.YOURDATASOURCE.HouseIncomes.AddNew();
        houseIncome.Participants = entity; //THIS ASSIGNS THE FOREIGN KEY RELATIONSHIP TO ITS PARENT
        houseIncome.CurrentLevel = "Yes"; //FOR STRING
        houseIncome.CurrentLevel = true; //FOR BOOLEAN
    }
```

This code is inserting your child data, linked to your parent data automatically, and setting the Current Level to your desired value.

[image]

Hope this helps...

Comment: Is it possible to do make another field in the same table default to a number?  There is a lookup field called TypeOfWorkLookups in the HouseIncomes table which is a Many to 0.1 relationship to a table called TypeOfWorkLookups".  I would like it to default to 17  (which represents "Unknown" in the TypeOfWorkLookups table). I tried **'houseIncome.TypeOfWorkLookUp =17'** but get an int cannot convert message;

Comment: I think you may have to set that in the HouseIncome_Inserted table, just like you did in the Participants_Inserted table. just a guess but I'll try it Monday morning and get back to you.

Comment: I tried it and came up with the same conversion error.

Comment: If I could look at how it works I may be able to help, or think of another solution?

Comment: Here is what I am using for code:     "Namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class ApplicationDataService
    {
        partial void Participants_Inserted(Participant entity)
        {
            HouseIncome houseIncome = DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.HouseIncomes.AddNew();
            houseIncome.Participant = entity; //THIS ASSIGNS THE FOREIGN KEY RELATIONSHIP TO ITS PARENT
            houseIncome.CurrentLevel = true; //FOR BOOLEAN
            houseIncome.TypeOfWorkLookups = 17;
        }
    }
}'